# Populating a ListView w/ AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is probably not very elegant, but what I'm trying to do is connect to a web service, fetch the JSON, parse it, create an object out of it, add that object to an ArrayList and then use that ArrayList to populate my ListView.

I'm trying to do all of this with AsyncTask.

SUMMARY: doInBackgroud takes a String of a url, uses it to connect to a web service. I get the JSON data as a string, parse it, construct a new object out of the data, and add it to ArrayList. Then in `onPostExecute` I'm trying to set the listadapter using an `ArrayAdapter` that utilizes my ArrayList.

Here's what I have:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AllOffersListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "bla";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "bla";


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        new CreateArrayListTask().execute("http://example.com/sample.json");




    }

    private class CreateArrayListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Offer>> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(AllOffersListActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Fetching offers...");
            this.dialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Offer> doInBackGround(String...urls) {
            ArrayList<Offer> offerList = new ArrayList<Offer>();

            for(String url: urls) {
                OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                consumer.setTokenWithSecret("", "");

                try {

                    URL url1 = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();

                    // sign the request
                    consumer.sign(request);

                    // send the request
                    request.connect();


                    String JSONString = convertStreamToString(request.getInputStream());

                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);

                    JSONObject offerObject = jObject.getJSONObject("offer");

                    String titleValue = offerObject.getString("title");
                    //System.out.println(titleValue);

                    String descriptionValue = offerObject.getString("description");
                    //System.out.println(attributeValue);
                    JSONObject businessObject = offerObject.getJSONObject("business");
                    String nameValue = businessObject.getString("name");

                    Offer myOffer = new Offer(titleValue, descriptionValue, nameValue);

                    offerList.add(myOffer);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } 
            }
            return offerList; 

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Offer> offerList) {
            if(this.dialog.isShowing())
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Offer>(AllOffersListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, offerList));        
        }
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        if(inputStream != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];

            try {

                Reader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                int n;
                while((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);

                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }

    }

}
```

I'm seeing two errors. One is on my private Async class: `"The type AllOffersListActivity.CreateArrayListTask must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<Offer>>.doInBackground(String...)"`

Secondly, on my `doInBackGround` Override, I'm getting: `The method doInBackGround(String...) of type AllOffersListActivity.CreateArrayListTask must override or implement a supertype method`

What am I missing here?

Comment: For this to work, I had to do `String before = writer.toString();
   String after = before.substring(1, before.length()-2);
   return after;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a small typo; should be `doInBackground` instead of `doInBackGround`.

Comment: LOL. I always do that! Now, I'm having another problem. My ListView isn't populating :( I had assumed that when I use my ArrayList of Offer objects that my Offer class's toString method would automatically be called. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LuxuryMode What are you seeing? Are you certain your ArrayList gets properly populated?

Comment: The activity shows nothing after the ProgressDialog is dismissed. But no, I'm not sure if the ArrayList is properly populated in the first place. What's the easiest way to tell? Just add a log?

Comment: Looks like something's going wrong here. Here's the log: http://pastebin.com/5ngJWBKS

Comment: Whoops, that's the wrong log. Here's the right one: pastebin.com/qxjKaKxS I think the problem is that the JSON file contains multiple objects. How do I iterate through all of them and create multiple Offer objects?

Comment: Why doesn't the Override statement catch the typo?

Answer (score 2):

@LuxuryMode you have done mistake on `doInBackGround`

the correct spelling is `doInBackground`

asynctask must have to implement `doInBackground` method so it is not recognize this method because of wrong Name of method so it gives you error

```
 The method doInBackGround(String...) of type AllOffersListActivity.CreateArrayListTask must 
override or implement a supertype method
```

Comment: Thanks! New problem now. After the AsyncTask runs, my ListView isn't populated :(

Comment: Means which problem are you facing ? is your listview blank or any error?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  you are getting this error means you have not connect a class successfully try to print response value and check that values

Comment: Whoops, that's the wrong log. Here's the right one: http://pastebin.com/qxjKaKxS I think the problem is that the JSON file contains multiple objects. How do I iterate through all of them and create multiple Offer objects?